# How to save PHP form and codes in ckeditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I got a problem to save source code as form or PHP in ckeditor, I mean, when I save codes in "source" it's okay, but if I will edit it again,  it will remove some part of codes automatically, like form id , form class, div class, even JavaScript, just it's fine with HTML code, but If I'll add PHP code, it can be saved but after edit the page, it will remove some classed in PHP, how to solve it ?

> why it will remove some classed and PHP code automatically after editing the page in ckeditor ?

This is an example for my problem 
I'm going to save this code in ckeditor

```
    <li>        
      <label for="senderName">Your Name</label>     
      <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Please type your name" required="required" maxlength="40" />            <li>Your Name</li>
    </li>
```

But after save, it will remove some part of codes and it will save like this:

```
    <li>Your Name</li>
```

why automatically ckeditor will remove input, label, placeholder and etc? 
How can I solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the best practice to save your PHP code withi ckeditor in DB because it will not work as expected by you.

But this might help you to getting rid of restriction some tag in ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where shall I add above line of code ?